# Groovy Postbuild Plugin manager.getLogMatcher regex returns null if parentheses are present in string

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

Jenkins Groovy Postbuild Plugin `manager.getLogMatcher` regex returns `null` if parentheses are present in string.

Jenkins console output contains string:

```
(origin/pull-requests/1365/merge)
```

I need to get number from string 1365 and use:

```
manager.getLogMatcher("^origin/pull-requests/(.*?)/merge*").matches()
```

it fails with:

```
Java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method matches() on null object
```

but if I delete parentheses:

```
origin/pull-requests/1365/merge
```

everything is ok.

Comment: I think you meant to put a .* at the end of your regex, rather than expect 0 or more "e". But I don't think this is the source of your problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [sources](https://github.com/jenkinsci/groovy-postbuild-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jvnet/hudson/plugins/groovypostbuild/GroovyPostbuildRecorder.java#L274) you'll find that the method you invoke may eventually return a `null` reference. Since you regular expression is invalid I guess this is the case. You need to take the parenthesis into consideration - especially if you regex starts with `^`. The two following should work:

```
"^\\(origin/pull-requests/(.*?)/merge.*"
^\\(origin/pull-requests/(.*?)/merge\\)
```

Comment: I don't think the outside parens were meant to be part of his regex. They are not in the quotes. I believe those are just surrounding the method call parameters. So being groovy, the outside parens could be dropped, but I don't think it would fix the problem.

Comment: @RobHales, yes you're right. This is just a guess of course. The output string may contain these parens literally. Further clarification is needed.